# How to simulate data for classification to be used in random forest in R?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I am wondering how I would simulate some data that could be used in a random forest for classification in R?

if it were for regression I'd do something like:

```
n <- 1000
p <- 3
e <- rnorm(n)
b <- 10

xVal <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)    # Create matrix wt 3 columns
colnames(xVal)<- paste0("x",1:p)      # Name columns
df <- data.frame(xVal)                # Create dataframe 

# Make x1 a useful predictor of y:
y <- df$x1 + e
df$y <- y
```

Which would look something like this:

```
head(df,3)
        x1         x2          x3            y
1 -0.6512695  0.3639012 -0.50231648 -0.296679882
2 -1.1393367 -0.8148882  0.33065078 -2.703743889
3 -0.2674592 -0.2670326 -0.15028117  1.024109832
```

Where x1 is a useful predictor of y and x2 & x3 are just random noise. Then Id just fit a random forest regression model to he data.

How would I achieve something similar for classification?

Comment: It seems that you are confusing the goal of an analysis (prediction/estimation versus classification) with the type of data available to achieve the goal (continuous normal versus binomial/multinomial categorical). I am guessing you have categorical data and are hoping to simulate something that has features analogous to that data. You should describe the features: numbers of features and their types and distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x1 = c(rnorm(500, 0,1), rnorm(500,3,1))
x2 = rnorm(1000)
x3 = rnorm(1000)
class= factor(rep(1:2, each=500))

plot(x1,x2, pch=20, col=class)
```

`x1` is a useful predictor of `class`. `x2` and `x3` are just noise.

Comment: Please excuse my, potentially, dumb question.. I'm relatively new to all this... But when I simulate the data as you've shown and then feed it to the random forest, it runs a regression random forest and not a classification one!?

Comment: I would not run random forest on three predictive variables,  but if you must, `DF = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,class); 
RFModel = randomForest(class~., data=DF)` worked for me. `RFModel$predicted` gives the predicted classes.

Comment: And can you explain why x1 is a useful predictor of class here? What's the relation?

Comment: The data was generated to make that true.  The first 500 points (class=1) are distributed around x1=0. The second 500 points (class=2) are distributed around x1=3. if you make a scatterplot, you will see the distinction  `plot(x1, x2, pch=20, col=class)`  Basically, if(x1<1.5) the point is more likely to be class1. If(x1>1.5) it is more likely to be class=2.